# Install tensorflow on Pythonista 3

Tags: tensorflow, pythonista

Hi when I try to use pip in launch stash it gives the following error

```
StaSh v0.6.18
Tip: Stop a running command by pressing the CC button (Ctrl-C on external keyboard)
[~/Documents]$ pip install tensorflow
Querying PyPI ... 
Error: Source distribution not available for tensorflow: 1.2.1
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow has C dependencies, which aren't supported on Pythonista. I work on my iPad on TensorFlow projects only through remote python environments;
An easy-to-use solution is Juno, which is a Jupyter notebook app for ipad and connects to remote jupyter environments like Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Don't understand the down vote. Is there an explanation?